# How to edit javascript file while testing Cordova app remotely in iPad

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, debugging, ipad

I'm testing a Cordova app in the iPad and I can open the Web Inspector to debug it, but instead of changing a couple lines of code in my JS and deploying it again to the iPad via Xcode every time I need a fix, I'd like to change the javascript file in the device and persist it.

I am able to open and edit the javascript file via the "Resources" tab in the Web Inspector, and it even gives me the possibility to save it, but it will only work for the simulator, not for the actual tablet.

So my question is how to persist the changes I made in that file in the device until the next deployment via Xcode? That would increase the productivity in the workflow by a lot.

Of course, if you're detecting a blond spot I might have, please bring it up!

I appreciate your time.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/2-install-mobile-app/

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting approach and I haven't really tested PhonGap lately. I'm using pure Cordova now, and so the question persists. But that's great do know, thank you very much for the info!

Comment: Just use cdvlive https://www.npmjs.com/package/cdvlive